# Execute cmd command on client Machine

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, client

At First here is my Code:

```
string host = l_hostname.Text;
string command = @"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe";
string arg = host;

Process.Start(command, arg);
```

As you see i will execute the `TightVNC viewer` with the target Hostname as a parameter.
When I run the code on my local machine IIS, it works perfectly. if I publish the code to my company IIS I get the error message `"File not found"`. Because TightVNC was not installed on the server.

How can I execute a cmd command on a client Machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using process.start it will always be started on the executing site = server (I asume you are using ASP or something similar)

Maybe use a hyperlink instead of starting a process? On the otherhand you may get security issues...

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110112140806AANF21Y

but as mentioned above: this will bring you security problems. AFAIK HTML can not start exe's on client machines. I know nothing about your requirements/architecture/system/etc., but maybe you should switch to a WinForms or WPF application. You could then deploy via ClickOnce or just put your exe on a network-file-share.

You maybe also able to provide .ink (shortcut) files.

Comment: my hyperlink: <a href="file:///C:\Program%20Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe">vnc</a> but nothing happend. when i click it on my local machine its startet a filedownload :/   is there no other solution with c#.net to execute a external file?

Comment: Actually you search a solution with HTML